# How to put script into functions.php and called in

Tags: php, html

I have a large script hard-coded in the bottom of my footer.

html (footer.php)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// anchor scrolling /
function filterPath(string) {
  return string
    .replace(/^\//,'')
    .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
    .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
  var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

  ...


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to put it in my functions.php file and just call it at this point if that is possible/will it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: why you are not create one .js file and will include it here

Comment: I have other .js files and functions files etc. I just want to put it in one of those and figured functions.php is the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make a separate js file for it and include it in that html page.
In this way , your code will be well maintainable and it can be cached by browser resulting in significant performance improvement.

Comment: how do I bring it into the page? I have got the php to wor but all my scripts are hard-coded

Comment: 1. Create a js file and copy all hardcoded js codes into it .
Note : dont use <script> inside js file

2. Write 
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/jsfile" /> where you hardcoded.

Let me know if you need any further clarifications.

Comment: If you have one existing js file , the  you can include the js code there .
Its not good to include it in php page.